# Notepad++ Find and remove between 2 strings including \r\n

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have a NotePad++ doc with content like below

```
DDDDDD
Quick | Brown
EEEEEE
DDDDDD
Fox | Jumps, Dog
EEEEEE
```

I would like to remove everything between the `DDDDDD` and `|` including `|` and the space after so the output is like

```
DDDDDD
Brown
EEEEEE
DDDDDD
Jumps, Dog
EEEEEE
```

Any ideas what regex expression can do this?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `DDDDDD\R\K.+?\|\h*`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
DDDDDD      # literally
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
.+?         # 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\|          # a pipe, must be escaped because it's a special character for regex
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Great answer! I was not aware of `\K`

Comment: @MátéJuhász: Thank you. It's a very usefull feature that act as a lookbehind (with variable length) [more infos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)